# What does this PHP do? Haven't seen it before

Tags: php

I have a php file,  im just wondering what it does. Im studying php so any help is appreciated

Here it is

```
<?PHP
$items = Array(
//added-10-nov-2011//
"XX11113154005564,37e9cece4d9f09fd50e4932a9873b685",
"XX11113164400456,6e1e5eba7c41984c87e13d80348f86dc",
"XX11113173701214,9cc77e266e4c0f172b4b98652c69dbe5",
"XX11113182201437,1a20947a598d25aa4263436eae0950c2",
"XX11113185805873,a79964c2355d1320599e9b28ac716746",
"XX11113193407109,f8de195a951e9dff88265e832e08f7a3",

);
echo $items[array_rand($items)];
/*
//old array-initcommit//
"XX11109392408136,f7b973046bcf801350d3c77b609b462b",
"XX11111160004664,cffa99324444334671b0ec2670e74c70",
"XX11111171804325,3676114df09bf484e39316462ea52195",
"XX11111180400794,28551d27fd35b3fb1e7e8c5f6a2219d5",
"XX11111184609870,767011776555c44b329f2acb3b4e3cd9",
"XX11110221705625,751dfb5def4ffd805cb21b0188b37ee2",
"XX11110255402072,408220eb85245d6e0d88c48cf18c909b",
"XX11110262508864,c8a3430bb7adaab1e3c5768734d64ba3",
"XX11110271704034,fa19ea833977ce4fcd5286282470c999",
"XX11110275703702,994791b261a96a14f38b55b6967d0c83",
*/
?>
```

Comment: This is just an array with items in it and sorts it randomly

Comment: Oh okay. What items are they? Thanks

Comment: Where did you get this file from?

Comment: Only the one that entered it can know. It just is a random string to me

Comment: PHP has got a great manual, for `array_rand`: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php

Comment: why so much down vote !?

Comment: If you don't know or won't say where this file is coming from, there's completely no context for us to work with making your question unanswerable. Closing.

Answer (score 2):

It declares an array of what appears to be random data and hash values and then echos one of them at random.

Without context as to what the hashes and data represent its really hard to indicate what is happening.

Comment: How does one decrypt the hashes, i want to know what it says

Comment: You can't (at least not without knowing a thing or two - and then some - about decryption), not without knowing which decryption method has been used. Also, the hashes could be salted, which makes it even harder to decrypt without knowing the salt.

Comment: Attempting to decrypt the hashes with md5 returns no results (doesn't mean they're not md5) and trying to encrypt the data (XX11...) does not return the hash given. My impression is that the data on the left of the comma is being hashed to the hash on the right and this is a primitive mapping array... again no context means this is only speculation

Answer (score 1):

It prints a random string of the strings:

```
"XX11113154005564,37e9cece4d9f09fd50e4932a9873b685",
"XX11113164400456,6e1e5eba7c41984c87e13d80348f86dc",
"XX11113173701214,9cc77e266e4c0f172b4b98652c69dbe5",
"XX11113182201437,1a20947a598d25aa4263436eae0950c2",
"XX11113185805873,a79964c2355d1320599e9b28ac716746",
"XX11113193407109,f8de195a951e9dff88265e832e08f7a3",
```

Answer (score 0):

The first part is an array with items in it stored in the `$items` variable, parts of it look like hashed strings. The second part echos a random item from that array by using `array_rand()` to get a random array key.

The last part appears to be an older list of similar values. What the data represents isn't clear without knowing where the data originally came from.

Answer (score 0):

It fills the array `$items` with values.

Looks like some hash (perhaps salt and hash)?

And prints a random item from the array.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily check simple stuff like that yourself [here](http://ideone.com/JA3SU), for example.